# I wrote a program which should terminate when 'n' or 'N' is entered but it doesn't work

Tags: c

It does not terminate when 'n' or 'N' is entered. How do i make it work?

Also, why will the `"\n\nGive n or N to terminate loop"` statement not work if I don't add `flush(stdin)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int i, n, sump, sumn;
  char ch;
  sump = 0;
  sumn = 0;
  do
  {

    printf("\nGive integer n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n > 0)
      sump = sump + n;
    else
      sumn = sumn + n;
    printf("\n\nGive n or N to terminate loop");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &ch);

  } while ((ch != 'n') || (ch != 'N'));
  printf("Sum of positive number=%d", sump);
  printf("\nSum of negative number=%d", sumn);
}
```

Comment: Two points: 1) Passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as causing *undefined behavior; And 2) `scanf("%c",&ch);` will read the newline left over from `scanf ("%d",&n);` (which you could have found out within a few second if you debugged your program).

Comment: im still new to programming , still learning :3 i cant seem to understand the 2 nd point, could you please guide me on how to fix it? thanks^^

Comment: You should indent your code properly. This is very important. I did it for you.

Comment: It should be `while ((ch!='n') && (ch!='N'))`. With all warnings enabled your compiler should tell you, that your current condition is always true.

Comment: `void main()` -> `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @StefanRiedel hello the code worked when i changed or into and. however shouldnt the program work even if i put or instead of and, since only one of them needs to be true to terminate the program?

Comment: @MysticSnow `(ch != 'n') || (ch != 'N')` translates to _ch is different from 'n' or ch is different from 'N'_. This condition is always true. Check out the possibilities on paper with ch being 'N', 'n' and 'X'.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you so much, my confusion is cleared now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for the numeric input (for the `n` variable) then that's added as a newline `'\n'`.

This newline is still in the input buffer of `stdin` when you read the character for `ch`.

And unlike many format which skips white-space (like newline) the `%c` format reads *all* characters, including that newline.

The #obvious" solution is simple: To ask `scanf` to skip any leading space, by adding a single space in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
//     ^
// Note space here
```

---

And as mentioned in a comment [by Stefan Riedel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365424/i-wrote-a-program-which-should-terminate-when-n-or-n-is-entered-but-it-doesn#comment120824864_68365424), the condition is incorrect as well. The negation of `ch == 'n' || ch == 'N'` is *not* `ch != 'n' || ch != 'N'`. Instead [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) dictate that the connecting logical operation must change as well:

```
ch != 'n' && ch != 'N'
```

Or you could simplify it:

```
tolower(ch) != 'n'
```

Comment: Nitpick: If `ch` is a negative value besides `EOF`, then calling `tolower(ch)` will cause undefined behavior. Therefore, it may be better to write `tolower( (unsigned char) ch )` instead.

Comment: thank you so much, now the program worked even without including "fflush" .

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It's unlikely that `scanf` will set `ch` to e.g. `EOF`. However, IIRC if `scanf` fails then the arguments will not be initialized, so better check what `scanf` returns instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: However, it can easily happen that `scanf` sets `ch` to a negative value, on platforms on which `char` is signed. Such a negative value should not be passed to `tolower` without first casting to `unsigned char`. Otherwise, according to [§7.4 p1 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1), the behavior is undefined (unless that negative value happens to be the value for `EOF`).

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char inp[100];
  int n, sump = 0, sumn = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    printf("Give integer, or \"n\" to stop: ");
    if(fgets(inp, sizeof(inp), stdin) == NULL) break;
    if(inp[0] == 'n' || inp[0] == 'N') break;
    n = atoi(inp);
    if (n > 0)
      sump = sump + n;
    else
      sumn = sumn + n;
  }
  printf("Sum of positive number=%d\n", sump);
  printf("Sum of negative number=%d\n", sumn);
}
```

In this program, there's not a separate prompt for the "n".
You can type a number, *or* type "n".
This is much more convenient for the person entering the numbers.
But it means you can't use `scanf` to read the input, because there's no way to ask `scanf` to, "read a number, or maybe the string 'n'".
But it's actually fine to not use `scanf` for input, because it turns out `scanf` is actually pretty terrible for user input.

This program reads a whole line of input, as text, using `fgets`.
Then it looks at the first character of the line to see if it's `'n'` or `'N'`.
Then, if it wasn't an N, it calls `atoi` to convert the string into an integer.

There are better ways to convert strings to integers -- that is, `atoi` has its problems, so it's recommended to use the more sophisticated `strtod` in "real" programs, but `atoi` is nice and simple, and sort of an intermediate step here.